# In emacs, how to disable comment auto-indent in C/C++?

Tags: emacs, indentation, mode

Sometimes I want to have temporary comments fully left justified on a line `(//)` or a block of lines `/* */`. However, `CC Mode` overrides this by auto-indenting upon typing the second key. In general, I like auto-indent for keywords, etc, but I would prefer it to be disabled for comments. (update: ie. I want to disable the way comment indentation is triggered  by the *c-electric-* key-bindings, but comments should still indent normally othewise)

I've tried putting these lines in `.emacs`, but it doesn't prevent the behaviour.

```
(c-electric-slash nil)
(c-electric-star nil)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
(eval-after-load 'cc-mode
  '(progn
     (define-key c-mode-base-map "/" 'self-insert-command)
     (define-key c-mode-base-map "*" 'self-insert-command)))
```

**Here's how I go about it:**

Find out the function bound to `/`: `C-h k /`

It says "/ runs the command c-electric-slash, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
function in 'cc-cmds.el'".

*(If you don't see the link to `cc-cmds.el`, then you don’t have the elisp sources installed. Assuming you're not on Windows, you can use your system’s package manager to install the `emacs-el` package and try again.)*

Follow that link to open `cc-cmds.el`. Searching for `c-electric-slash` doesn't find anything other than the function definition, so the keys aren't bound in this file. Searching in `cc-mode.el` from this directory reveals:

```
(define-key c-mode-base-map "/" 'c-electric-slash)
```

Now we know the name of the "keymap" in which to override the `/` keybinding.

If you add something like this to your init file, you'll probably get an error on startup:

```
(define-key c-mode-base-map "/" 'self-insert-command)
```

...because your init file is loaded before cc-mode.el is, and `c-mode-base-map` is undefined. So we use `eval-after-load` (as at the top of my answer). The first argument, `'cc-mode`, has to match the `provide` statement at the very end of cc-mode.el. If you don't know what the `progn` means, do `C-h f progn`.

If you like this style of learning/discovering Emacs, you might consider reading my ["How to learn Emacs"](http://david.rothlis.net/emacs/howtolearn.html).

Comment: Brilliant! What a great explanation! .. and it works, too :) ... Thank you... and I'll definitely be reading your suggested guide.

Comment: Suggestion: Update this to use `with-eval-after-load`

Comment: For what it's worth, I was struggling with this issue while creating a major mode derived from `c-mode`. By adding the two `define-key` lines to the definition of my mode's keymap (and changing `c-mode-base-map` to the name of my local map), I was able to eliminate this behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look to the `c-indent-comment-alist` & `c-indent-comments-syntactically-p` variables. See more information in help for this variables (`C-h v`) and in the sections "[Customizing Indentation](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Customizing-Indentation.html#Customizing-Indentation)" and "[Style Variables](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Style-Variables.html#Style-Variables)" of the CC-mode manual

Comment: I haven't read it all yet (let alone grappled with the new emacs jargon), but I have a feeling that your suggestion changes ***how*** things indent. I don't want to change the indentation behaviour: I do want comment lines to indent normally in most situations, but I do not want *(c-electric-slash* and *(c-electric-star* to dictate that the indentation occurs ***when*** `/` or `*` are pressed. Perhaps it is as simple as re-binding the `/` and `*` keys from the *electric* functions to `self-insert-command`, but only for *CC Mode* (that's the bit I don't know how to do).